# Imprimir varios objetos de tipo struct en c++

Tags: c++

Buenas tengo una estructura Struct de nombre Canciones, del cual he creado 5 elementos así:

```
struct Canciones{
    int id;
    string nombreArtista;
    string nombreCancion;
    int minutosCancion;
    int segundosCancion;
    
}cancion1={06,"Mi gente","J Balvin, Willy William",3,5},
    cancion2={101,"My way","Calvin Harris",3,39},
    cancion3={201,"Dont be shy","Dont be shy",2,20},
    cancion4={234,"Hey Brother","Avicii",4,15},
    cancion5={54,"Ojitos Lindos","J Balvin, Willy William",4,18};
```

Ahora lo que quiero es imprimir las 5 canciones en un solo bucle, es decir que se imprima primero cancion1, en la siguiente iteración se imprima la información de la cancion2, y así sucesivamente sin tener que ir de una por una.

Comment: probaste añadiendo los structs declarados a un array y usar un for para recorrerlo? Si es que se pueden añadir structs a arrays

Comment: Lo hice pero únicamente con la id, es decir el array almacena el id de cada canción, no veía como poder agregar cada elemento de canción.

Answer (score 0):

Pues para poder mostrar esas canciones en un bucle tendrás que agregarlas si o si a
un array o a cualquier otra estructura de datos que te permita iterar la colección de elementos (como lo son el vector, array, matriz, list, etc) pero como ya tienes creadas las canciones cada una en su respectiva variable  hay dos formas de agregarlas a un array.

Una forma de llenar el array es asignarlas una por una en su respectiva posición que ocupará dentro del array

```
const int TAM = 5;
Cancion lista[TAM];

lista[0] = cancion1;
lista[1] = cancion2;
lista[2] = cancion3;
lista[3] = cancion4;
lista[4] = cancion5;
```

La otra forma es utilizando la lista de inicialización

```
const int TAM = 5;
Cancion lista[TAM] = {cancion1,cancion2,cancion3,cancion4,cancion5};
```

Luego de haber llenado el array de cualquiera de las dos formas solo falta iterar el array para mostrar las canciones

```
for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
    cout<<"Id      : "<<lista[i].id<<"\n";
    cout<<"Cancion : "<<lista[i].nombreCancion<<"\n";
    cout<<"Artista : "<<lista[i].nombreArtista<<"\n";
    cout<<"Duracion: "<<lista[i].minutosCancion<<":" 
        <<lista[i].segundosCancion<<"\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo habitual en estos casos es definir un operador de inyección a flujo de datos:

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const Cancion &c)
{
    return o
        << c.id << ' ' << c.nombreArtista << ' ' << c.nombreCancion << ' '
        << c.minutosCancion << ':' << c.segundosCancion;
}
```

Con ese operador definido, puedes enviar objetos `Cancion` a la consola de la manera habitual:

```
Cancion c{0, "Iron Butterfly", "In-A-Gadda-Da-Vida", 17, 4};

std::cout << c;
```

Si quieres un bucle para todas las canciones, tendrás que definirlas en una colección de datos:

```
struct Cancion
{
    int id;
    string nombreArtista;
    string nombreCancion;
    int minutosCancion;
    int segundosCancion;
    
} canciones[] = {
//          ^ <--- Formacion de canciones.
    {06,"Mi gente","J Balvin, Willy William",3,5},
    {101,"My way","Calvin Harris",3,39},
    {201,"Dont be shy","Dont be shy",2,20},
    {234,"Hey Brother","Avicii",4,15},
    {54,"Ojitos Lindos","J Balvin, Willy William",4,18}
};
```

Y después usa el bucle:

```
int main()
{
    for (const auto &c : canciones)
        cout << c << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHLTsMwEDzXX7EKUh@SQX0AgjRUgnJACMSRA3AwjgmLEruynaKqyreXjdMCAUQiJfLuzOysRy4W@zIXOtts9lDLvEwVJGict0oUM/ZVowrqbMZY6egPWhTKLYRU4Hw6ZYzapfQwF1qi0WzNOqg9ILU6DRO0KZ6tOrcenRc/y1vetKEVqEtvXLvoVFbq9FsV6GEVyOas3MMTnAENXg@PeXSLkCntVcSja7gQ@RI1h3vM81X4oigiPuFHFSf8aDgiwgrexYrg8wCGK2Etuho0OQ2ocY26NOTkmZZ@raGt05iPhw1wcsijK7WCC2v8q7IEPF@iRIz4IR81I48IcveGtCTcYL3Vfz6JdVKxKtxyGsfbcKBrFsoKbywkSf9Hh4M02n3mAV05qDOxypdWg2GdTpKAPMCUuNCjNxxbEf3R2ak1nZ1IO63QjLe0X5lVjIWABep@cPRC9vuNV0EqZBTir0gHNEOa0ge1oPyoe3QPu0WGpLjZfAA)</kbd>.

---

Por cierto, he cambiado el nombre de tu `struct` de `Canciones` a `Cancion` ya que no tiene sentido que el nombre esté en plural para un objeto que sólo almacena un dato en lugar de varios.